# Fill postgresql table with CSV and UTF-8 encoding files

Tags: postgresql, csv, encoding, utf-8, phppgadmin

I create custom Database with UTF-8 Encoding in postgreSQL (PHPPgAdmin) and
create CSV file with Excel in windows too.
I want to import CSV file to one of my table.
When I open my csv file in Windows, some characters in the form Are shown with ? symbol.
My CSV file has UTF-8 encoding. when I run Query to Import Data from That CSV file PostgresSQL with this command

```
COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email)
FROM 'C:\sampledb\persons.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

It shows error :
**ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc2 0xd0**
How can I insert my file into a table without corrupting its characters utf-8 encoding?
thank you

Comment: 0xc2 0xd0 is not a valid utf8 sequence, so your CSV file is not utf8 encoded. Possibly CP1252 (improbable) or some other windows dialect.

Comment: Once you do figure out the encoding of the CSV file, `COPY` has an `ENCODING` option where you can specify it on import. Otherwise Postgres uses the client encoding.